# Stock inventory for products sold in different packing sizes

Tags: stock, inventory

I'm selling a product, which I import in packs of 1440 pieces. I split these up and sell them in bags of 100, 720, or 1440 pieces. Until now I have set these up as one configurable product with 3 options for number. But how would it be possible to keep track of stocks in the system?

If I have 1 pack with 1440 pieces, I need the system to show that if a pack with 100 pieces is sold, the 1440 pack is out of stock (because now only 1340 pieces left). Is it possible to do this in Magento?
I don't want to make it a single product where people can type any number, because I want to sell only these 3 sizes of bags - not for instance 17 or 132 pieces.

Answer (score 0):

what i understood from your question you want to Sell products in Batch of 100 , 70 , 1000 as so on

what i Would Suggest

1. Rather than making them configurable assign them as custom options
2. Use JS to assign value to assign to quantity box that value in custom option and make quantity un-editable in rest of fields

Or

Observe the order success and use the value - 1 ( as on order success one quantity will be automatically deducted ) in custom option and deduct inventory programmatically